# Explanation of Java code needed

Tags: java

I am not sure how to phrase my question as I am actually asking what this is that I just saw in a code.

You have a class:

```
public class thing{
(code)
}

thing something; 
thing whatever;
```

In netbeans the words something and whatever turns green.

What am I actually doing right here? Am I creating my own variable? Does it have a name? Can I search it up?

To give this some more context I am going to start to work on trees, and I see this initializing (or whatever it is) all the time.

```
 public class Node{
    Node right; 
    Node left; 
    Node root; 
    }
```

Comment: thing something; and thing whatever;  has to be within class declaration.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but does thing kind of thing have a name? Am I making a new variable? Does it have name? What's actually happening? Int, Double, and stuff like I know. I have never seen you can write the class name first, and something afterwards just like it was a variable.

Comment: 'something' and 'whatever' are now instances of your 'thing' class

Comment: Not exactly, because they are never constructed :D They are just null pointers

Comment: They are not instances of thing unless they are constructed.  They are just variables of type thing.

Comment: Thank you for that, because now I have a pointer to what I am actually doing, and search it up and learn.

Comment: To learn about this, should I search in google "instances of class in java"?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a reference of a class.
creating reference is similar to declaring a variable in java i.e,
"int a" here, "a" is the variable of type integer. Similarly, when we define references we declare it in a following way:
  eg: "Integer a" here, a is the reference of type Integer.
In your case "thing" is a class and you are actually creating reference of class thing hence it is appearing green in colour beacause it is a kind of variable of type "thing". But don't get confused, if you deaclare variable of type some class then it is reference but when you declare variable of type primitive data types then it is variable.
In your second example "Node" is the class and right,left,root are the references of type NODE.

Comment: Oh this might be very helpful. I am gonna search up "reference of a class". Thanks.

Comment: is Node LeftChild; for example the same as writing Node LeftChild = new Node();? Or something almost the same?

Comment: When you write "Node LeftChild" it means you just created a reference of class "Node".Writing "new Node()" means you just created the object of class "Node". And when you write "Node LeftChild =new Node()" it means you have a reference "LeftChild" pointing to a object of class Node.Reference is nothing but a kind of container which contains or holds the address of the object of class.

Comment: Let me explain the line "Node LeftChild=new New()" for you. You created a refrence called "LeftChild" of class Node to point the object of class Node.Parenthesis at the end of "Node()" is actually calling the default constructor of class Node which will initialize the the instance data members of class "Node".

Comment: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html).Here you can get the better explanation about references and object.

Comment: Oh i am starting to understand. https://gyazo.com/dd36943ecb26ed6f9a43f1f07fb1fa92 Here is a little bit of code I have I will write in a next reply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86550/discussion-between-aparajit-and-david-lund).

Comment: Node Node1 = new Node(4,"Nodename"); You are creating a new object Node with (4,"Nodename") and a reference to this object is Node1.  Node LeftChild is a reference to the class itself .. mhmm .. here is where it's get tricky. It must be to track all the objects of that class or something?